# I need in using $ variables and some kind of comparison in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$Filial = "^(SPP\.|SSL\.)$"
$PC = "^(N\.|V\.|D\.)$"
$Serve = "^(SRV\.)$

$ServerList = Get-DhcpServerInDC | select IPADdress, DNSName
foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
    Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server.IPAddress |
        select ScopeId |
        ForEach-Object {
            Get-DHCPServerv4Lease -ScopeId $_.ScopeID -ComputerName $Server.DNSName -AllLeases |
                Where {
                    $_.Hostname -isnot  "$Filial-$Server-$PC" -and -and
                    $_.Hostname -notlike "$_NULL"
                }
| Select-Object ScopeId,IPAddress,HostName,ClientID,AddressState |
            Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path C:\Scripts\teste\tste.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Force
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. Please format your code properly using the `{}` button, or tags <pre></pre> or CTRL+k. Also I don't see a question.

Comment: Not sure what are you looking for. Need more information.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, so I want the program to work this way, but it can not do this validation for the variable. it does not read that the first term can be 3 types of strings and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Filial = "^(SPP\.|SSL\.)$"

$PC = "^(N\.|V\.|D\.)$"

$Serve = "^(SRV\.)$


$ServerList = Get-DhcpServerInDC | select IPADdress, DNSName
foreach ($server in $serverlist) 
{

Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server.IPAddress |
    select ScopeId |

ForEach-Object {

Get-DHCPServerv4Lease -ScopeId $_.ScopeID -ComputerName $Server.DNSName -AllLeases |
            Where {
                $_.Hostname -isnot  "$Filial-$Server-$PC" -and -and
                $_.Hostname -notlike "$_NULL"
            }

 | Select-Object ScopeId,IPAddress,HostName,ClientID,AddressState |
        Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path C:\Scripts\teste\tste.csv -NoTypeInformation 
  -Encoding UTF8 -Force





I tried isnot, nothing, not like, anything fucking anything works out, I wish the name not to be pulled out is any of those.
```